# Запустить скрипт только один раз?

Tags: php, cron

В общем ситуация такая. Есть скрипт, который может работать в некоторых редких случаях больше чем интервал в cronjob, но запускать его при этом нужно каждую минуту, так как в 95% случаев он отрабатывает за несколько секунд. Нужно исключить возможность повторного запуска.
Сразу оговорюсь, это бесплатный хостинг, поэтому SSH доступа нет, и мониторить процессы не получается. Остаётся лишь реализовать это средствами PHP

Пробовал так

```
//Статический файл который будет хранить имя временного файла
$lockFilename = __DIR__ . '/lock.dat';

//Проверяем существует ли временный файл
if (file_exists($lockFilename) && ($lock = file_get_contents($lockFilename)) && file_exists($lock)) {
    echo "Cron running now {$lock}\n";
    exit();
}

//Файл должен умереть при закрытии дескриптора
$tmpHandle = tmpfile();

//Получаем имя временного файла
$metaData = stream_get_meta_data($tmpHandle);

//Записываем имя временного файла в статический файл
file_put_contents($lockFilename, $metaData['uri']);

//Cron симуляция
echo "Cron started\n";

sleep(20);

echo "Cron stopped\n";
exit();
```

Но файл остаётся, если прервать скрипт через Ctrl+C

Думал решить задачу через memcache и время жизни ключа, но обратно таки бесплатный хостинг не предоставляет memcache в распоряжение

Comment: всё правильно вы остановили процесс а значит код который удоляет tmp file не выполнился

Comment: Как вариант писать в файл дату и если она допустим вчерашняя удалять файл, но вообще Сtrl+C это не корректное завершения программы и лучше отслеживать такие случаи

Comment: @Naumov
из документации просто
`The file is automatically removed when closed (for example, by calling fclose(), or when there are no remaining references to the file handle returned by tmpfile()), or when the script ends.` Если создавать файл допустим через WinApi **CreateFile** и флагом `FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE`, то даже если убить процесс на ходу, файл удалится. Видимо в PHP и Linux обстоит всё не так(((

Comment: @users
Да как вариант я думал об этом. Можно даже облегчить и не заморачиваться с временным файлом. Но в таком случае нужно ждать какое-то время и пропустить намного больше итераций чем хотелось бы.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.register-shutdown-function.php не?

Comment: Или лучше вот http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909798/register-php-shutdown-function-to-fire-when-a-script-is-killed-from-the-command

Comment: @rjhdby первый вариант отлавливает только ошибки, 2 рабочий, но есть хостинги где нет работают php pcntl

Comment: Ну и как вариант с файлами и блокировкой файла: https://secure.php.net/manual/ru/function.flock.php

Comment: @rjhdby К несчатью на хостинге таки нет 
`Fatal error: Call to undefined function pcntl_signal()`

Comment: @Ninazu если у вас нет доступа в консоль, то кто может нажать `CTRL+C`?

Comment: @users
А вот `flock` работает. Если покажете рабочий пример, то отмечу решением.

Comment: @rjhdby Это смоделированная ситуация. Проверяю изначально у себя на локалке. Просто нужен способ который гарантированно будет работать при пессимистических сценариях

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант с блокировкой файла:

```
$fp = fopen("lock", "w+");

if (flock($fp, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB)) { // выполняем  блокировку

    /*
     * Тут код который нужно выполнить 
     */ 

    flock($fp, LOCK_UN); // отпираем файл
} else { 
    echo "Не удалось получить блокировку, файл уже заблокирован!";
}

fclose($fp);
unlink("lock");
```

---

Вариант с обработкой сигналов:

```
declare(ticks = 1); // включить обработку сигнала    

function sigint()  { 

    exit();

}  
pcntl_signal(SIGINT, 'sigint');  
pcntl_signal(SIGTERM, 'sigint'); 

/*
 * Тут код который нужно выполнить 
 */
```

Answer (score 1):

Совсем аццкий вариант. Создаем таблицу с одним полем TIMESTAMP и с одной записью

```
$conn = new mysqli(....);
$conn->begin_transaction();
$conn->query('UPDATE dummy SET stamp=NOW()');

......

//самая последняя строка
$conn->commit();
$conn->close();
```

При аварийном завершении скрипта будет rollback и снятие блокировки с таблицы